# How to deploy logic app with dynamic connection of Azure Storage table

Tags: azure

I'm trying to deploy the logic app application through CI CD for each env, say DEV/TEST/ACC/PRD.
Azure storage table used in logic apps should be dynamic based on the env.
Could you please help me with a solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the automated deployment documentation here it shows how to setup the arm templates for deploying logic apps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview#workflow-definition-and-parameters

In terms of the different variables for various environments you need to define them as parameters in the template

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview#workflow-definition-and-parameters

If you have sensitive information like passwords, connection strings etc you can store them in Azure Devops Library variables (or as secrets if you are in Github), guidance for that below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview#workflow-definition-and-parameters